# other website/store/store front does not load; .htaccess file is missing

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, .htaccess

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

My hosting company created a new account for me and moved my existing account there. That replaced the broken cPanel account and I am now able to access the database via the phpMyAdmin in Cpanel.

The emails and website were cloned now in the new account.

Then they transferred the Domain and Aliases from the old account to the new.

Now the other websites/stores/storefronts do not load. There is a website suspended Error.

I've noticed the .htaccess file is missing. Could that be the reason for this?

---

**UPDATED on November 9th:**

**The .htaccess file is actually there** and it has all the addional domains/websites/stores/store fronts listed in it as it was before the migration.

Everything apears to be setup as before like this:

https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

but I now get a generic Magento Error when trying to access the additional website/store/store front by using that domain:

```
Error 503:
Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2014 Magento Inc.
```

---

**UPDATED later on November 9th:**

*My hosting company resolved the issue but they did not tell me what was wrong. They claimed that I un-suspended the old account (the one we were using before the migration) and that created this issue. I don't think I did. But everything works now except for our images which are still not loading on the back-end (in the Magento Admin panel)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are having too many problems with your host.If you have a good website with big data i suggest you go for **Nexcess** as host . They have a good support and you dont have to worry about anything .
As for the .htacceess missing , this is usually a hidden file and cant be seen directly . If you have access in terminal , run a `ls -alht` to see if .htaccess , if it dont im adding the default .htaccess from magento 1.9.1 :

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none
```

If that doesnt help check this :

- Fix permissions of the files
- Check the app/etc/config.xml (if you have one and if database name is same as on server)
- Check the url on `core_config_data` are the same as declarated on server.
- Check the IP of the Domain , if it looks ok .

What do you mean with : `There is a website suspended Error.` ?

Comment: @Yigen Guxholli Thank you for that. I will definetely move to another host. I want to install and setup the newest version of Magento there and import my products and customers from this 1.9.1 store. I will look into Nexcess - thanks. The first Error was a hosting Error message - the kind that comes up if I suspend an account via the WebHostManager (kind of a Cpanel but for more domains/accounts). Their Level3 support worked on it for about 8 hours now and when I try to access one of the other websites/stores - I get a Magento Error which says:

Comment: Service Temporarily Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2014 Magento Inc.

Comment: The way I have the addional domains/websites/stores/store fronts setup is as here: https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains

Comment: Is there a guide on which files need to have which permissions on Magento 1.9.1?

Comment: I don't have  app/etc/config.php -- I only have  app/etc/config.xml

Comment: Where would one find the core_config_data ?

Comment: Where shall I check the IP of the Domain?

Comment: @Allysin i meant for config.xml so you have it , jst check if the db name its same as you did set up on server , check the other credentials too . Search on your db for  core_config_data table and click there , you will see the websites url where are pointing  .  The ip you can check on Server Info also check into the website you bought the domain (for ex: godaddy/namecheap) .

Comment: Here you can find the permissions https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html

Comment: My hosting company resolved the issue but they did not tell me what was wrong. They claimed that I un-suspended the old account (the one we were using before the migration) and that created this issue. I don't think I did. But everything works now except for our images which are still not loading on the back-end (in the Magento Admin panel)

Comment: Glad its fixed :)